# Untrusted Groovy Script Security in Java

Tags: java, groovy

We are attempting to provide scriptable elements with in an "enterprisy" product. We would like to use groovy but we are having difficulty securing very basic things.

For example, we would like to prevent a client from simply going

```
Class.forName("my.company.internal.SecruityTools").runAsAwesome(...)
```

We've installed a security manager with a policy that only allows `accesDeclaredMembers` and have overwritten the `checkPackageAccess` method and only allow white listed packages. Unfortunately, the default classLoader chain appears to just bypass this, and load the class any how.

It would seem like this is a fairly common / discussed problem, but I cannot for the life of me find a library or even a good blog post on how to lock down untrusted scripts with in the context of a much greater application.

Has any one done this succesfully? Am I missing some fairly obvious posts / concepts? Is there already a solid library for this? Maybe `Groovy.tinFoilHatMode(true)`?

Comment: Maybe [this answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6490674/274466) is of some assistance? The answer points to [this blog post](http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/customizing_groovy_compilation_process), which offers a plausible mechanism for preventing this sort of thing...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there are quite a few dynamic language features that could prevent any kind of AST protections. Something like object.("ge"+t" +"ClassLoader")."fo"+$rname or something silly like that.

Comment: @Ambience Have you tried the procedures suggested by ig0774?  I don't believe you can evade them with tricks like you suggest, and if you can, this is something that should be reported back to the Groovy team asap.

Comment: We are already using it to protect against some overt attacks, but even in the comments of that article some one points out that you could simply use method iteration to get a method pointer and execute what ever you wanted (and I am sure other groovy-foo beyond my fledgling understanding). But we will see if we can find a nice way to lock it down. I feel like a cleaner solution would involve setting up the classloader chain in such a way that it always checked class loading against the security manager or some other gatekeeper.

Comment: You can also see if my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681413/how-do-you-forbid-users-from-doing-evil-things-in-groovy-scripts/36706404#36706404 is of any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Groovy Sandbox](http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org/). You can use it to stop things like `System.exit(0)` or `new File(“/etc/passwd”)`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [java-sandbox](http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html). There is also a tutorial of how to use it with groovy: http://blog.datenwerke.net/2013/06/sandboxing-groovy-with-java-sandbox.html

Comment: I will take a look at this when I get a chance to circle back, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [GroovyCodeSource](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyCodeSource.html)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but that appears to be implicitly wrapped around compiled sources and simply helps a policy be narrowed for scripts. Our code defines a very strict policy for ALL sources with in the evaluation thread. So this would help us "scope" our permission but doesn't do anything magical to cause the Class.forName permissions to start being validated (not that I can see just looking at the internal groovy references to it).

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing was a combination of the things above, but the real magic sauce was implementing [this AST transformer](https://gist.github.com/sskrla/757b2192dbbd0ae7bc5f) that wrapped any expression (including `this`, or an implicit `this`) in an access check.